# How do I create full path given index level and corresponding folder name?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, path

In Excel, I have index levels (1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 2, etc.) and corresponding folder name. I want a function to be take each level and concatenate corresponding folder names with a slash between levels (as to mimic a file path).

I don't know whether number of levels matters, but my full dataset has 6 levels (1.3.3.2.6.1). [Hyperlinked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1GcG.png) shows what I'm hoping to achieve.

Edit: see how 10 takes 1 / 10 after function applied, same with 20's, 30's, etc.
| Index | End of Path | Function Applied |
| ----- | ----------- | ---------------- |
| 1 | Corporate Matters | Corporate Matters |
| 9.5 | Network and phones | Network and phones |
| 10 | Environmental, Health, & Safety | Corporate Matters/Environmental, Health, & Safety |
| 10.1 | Environmental site assessments (Phase I or Phase II reports) | Corporate Matters/Environmental, Health, & Safety/Environmental site assessments (Phase I or Phase II reports) |

Comment: Please provide the example data [as a table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) instead of a picture on an external link.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. Your index level column is always ordered, as per your example
2. You have Office 365
3. Your data is in `A1:B10`

in `C1`:

`=TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTER(B$1:B$10,LEFT(A$1:A$10,LEN(A$1:A$10))=LEFT(A1,LEN(A$1:A$10))))`

and copied down.

Comment: doesn't work when numbers are 2 digits. e.g. 10 will create a path of 1/10... it sees only first number, not what's between the decimal points

Comment: Then perhaps you should heed marcell's comment and add some copiable, realistic data.